# Why one can not call main method from another method

Tags: java, program-entry-point

`main` method is static, So why one don't call it from another method.

```
Class Main(){
  public static void main(String[] args){

  }
  public static void abc(){
    Main.main(String arr);
  }
}
```

Why one can not call `main` method from another method.

Comment: In your case you are not calling the abc method, so how should it call the main method then?

Comment: You should learn basics first.

Answer (score 2):

You can call it, but you need to pass it a String array :

```
public static void abc(){
    Main.main(new String[] {"something"});
}
```

or at least an empty array :

```
public static void abc(){
    Main.main(new String[0]);
}
```

You should also declare the `Main` class properly (thanks to Chetan's comment):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
...
```

Comment: Also, `Class Main()` is wrong. It should be `Class Main`

Comment: @ChetanKinger You mean `class Main`

Comment: Your comment makes my comment ironic :(. Yup. It should be `class Main`

Comment: @Eran Another valid way would be `public static void main(String...args)` then you could call `Main.main()`.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Your comment was helpful :)